# Random from listbox

Tags: vb.net, random

there has been many posts about this but nobody seems to have my problem.

I have a list box with letters a-z (line for each letter)

using

```
    Dim rancon As New Random
    Dim rc As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
    Label5.Text = lcon.Items.Item(rancon.Next(rc)).ToString
```

all it is doing is chosing randomly, 1 of the first 7 or 8 characters.

can anyone advise?

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: well, I have a list with 26 characters, so want it to pick randomly any one of those 26

Comment: to my limited understanding with my code I have declared the count of lines (with rc) and picked randomly one of those

Comment: Why are you setting rc to `ListBox1.Items.Count` instead of `lcon.Items.Count`?

Comment: if you are declaring a new Random everytime it will repeat, but even so, Random does not mean unique

Comment: because I am a numpty! that was it thanks ;) I did have another list box with less characters, that's why it was only picking the wrong amount of numbers. thanks a million. glad it was something simple!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you expect that the random always chooses a different item in the `ListBox`. Therefore you have to reuse the same `Random` instance since the default constructor derives the seed(which is used to initialize the pseudorandom number generator) from  the current system time.
If you call this code very fast(for example in a loop), the seed will always be the same. Hence you get repeating numbers/items.

To avoid this you could make the `Random` a field in the class:

```
Private rancon As New Random

Public Sub YourMethod()
    Dim rc As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
    Label5.Text = ListBox1.Items(rancon.Next(rc)).ToString()
End Sub
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default seed value is **derived from the system clock** and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   **identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers**. This problem can be avoided by using a single
>   Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around
>   it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then
>   explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32)
>   constructor.

---

Note that i've also used `ListBox1.Items` instead of `lcon.Items` in case that was a typo.